# Probability of exactly two zeros in a binary number with $6$ digits

Tags: probability, probability-theory

What is the probability that there are exactly two zeros in a arbitrary 6-digits binary number?

This is my attempt:
$$P(X = 2) = \frac1{6^6}{6 \choose 2}2^2 4^4$$ 
But that is the wrong answer. What is my mistake and how is one supposed to think to solve this problem?

Comment: What are $2^2$, $4^4$, and $6^6$? A binary number consists of zeros and ones.

Comment: Is $000111$ a six digit number or not?

Comment: Assuming everything is uniform, the probability is the ratio of the number of sequences with exactly 2 zeros ( $\binom{6}{2}$ ), and the total number of sequences $2^6$. 

If you give me the reason behind why you're multiplying with $2^2$ and $4^4$, I can try and correct the conceptual error behind your mistake.

Comment: @5xum yes it is but it has 3 zeros not 2.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I am using the black and white marbles procedure. You choose randomly n marbles out of a box. That can be done $6*5 = 30$ ways when $n=6$ in this case. Then there are $(2*6)^2$ ways to choose a white marble (in our case the zeros) and $(4/6)^{6-2}$ ways to choose the black marbles (in our case the ones)

Comment: @zhoraster read my above comment :)

Comment: @Mathguy007 Why would there be $30$ ways to pick $n$ marbles out of a box? There are $n$ marbles, the first can be one of two colors, the second can be one of two colors and so on, so where did you get $6\cdot 5$?

Answer (score 1):

There are ${6\choose 2} = 15$ ways to select the position of the two zeroes, so all together, there are $15$ numbers with only two zeroes.

How many numbers are there all together?

Comment: Yes, I think that´s how it works, but the leading digit should be 1 (100000-111111), so $2^5$ numbers altogether and ${5 \choose 2}$ with exactly 2 zeros so $P(X=2)=\frac{{5 \choose 2}}{2^5}=\frac{5}{16}$

Comment: @PeterMelech In comments, OP specifically said that $000111$ is also a $6$ digid number.

Comment: Ah, sorry Idid´t see this.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to observe that in a binary number drawn uniformly, the 1's and 0's occur with equal probability. Then this is exactly the same problem as the probably of exactly 2 heads in 6 coin flips. First, start of by counting how many ways 2 heads can happen in 6 coin flips and then by calculating the probability of any one occurrence (eg what the probability of observing HHTTTT). The total probability is the sum of each occurrence's probability.